# Android - closing progress dialog from event handler

Tags: android

I have a web service request in my Android app which might take a second or two to run. I have an event handler which fires when it completes. I am trying to show a dialog to show the progress of this request.

So far I have this:

```
var progressDialog = Android.App.ProgressDialog.Show(this.Activity, "Please wait...", "Communicating with server...", true);
new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate {
                   WCFClient WCF = WCFService();
                   WCF.TestCompleted+= TestCompleted;
                   WCF.TestAsync(GetID());

                   progressDialog.Dismiss();}
                 )
           ).Start();
```

The problem is obvious, the dialog displays and disappears in a flash. I am declaring var progressDialog in the UI thread. How can I reference it again in an event handler?

I would normally use RunOnUIThread but I cannot target "progressDialog" that way as it does not exist in my layout.

It seems like this should be easy - am I missing something in my approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. The first is there is a memory leak. You are holding onto the progress dialog in your thread. If the user rotates the device, your Activity will be killed but the garbage collector won't be able to garbage collect the reference because your Thread is holding onto it.

Secondly, you cannot update the UI from another thread, you have to update on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Handler, pass a reference to the other threads (in the constructor), then when needed send a message to UIthread to dismiss the progress dialog.

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  if (progressDialog.isShowing()) progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
    };
```

in the thread, do this:

```
mHandler.obtainMessage().sendToTarget();
```

Also there is another issue in the code, you don't seem to check if you completed the task, BEFORE dismissing the dialog.